# ByteArrayOutputStream write IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, bytebuffer, bytearrayoutputstream

I keep getting this exception despite my offset/limit being within bounds, so im not sure whats going on here?

I have a ByteArrayOutputstream that is currently empty and a byte array of size 1024. Debugging i can see my offset is 283, perfectly within bounds, and my length is just the length of my input byte array (1024). Everything looks fine, so what could be causing this code to be throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, im truly stumped here

[Debugger Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rjRl.png)

```
public void parseBytes(byte[] bytes, int length, String format) {//Buffer input bitstream until we reach msgSize indicated in header, then send fullfilled bitstream to sendRDM()
        if(!doneReading){
            int bytesOver = msgSize - byteBuffer.size()+28-length; //must be smaller, question is if we need to read socket again to fulfill (how many are we short or over)
            if(bytesOver <= 0){//negative or 0 means we can fulfill msgsize and have left over(start of next msg) (read partial bitstream)
                int off = length+bytesOver;
                byteBuffer.write(bytes, 0, off);
                leftOvers.write(bytes, off+1, length); //if bytesOver = 0, leftOver will be empty
                doneReading = true;
                byte[] inputStream = byteBuffer.toByteArray();
                byteBuffer.reset(); //empty buffer for next message
                sendRDM(inputStream, inputStream.length, format);
            }
            ...
```

Comment: This looks suspect `leftOvers.write(bytes, off+1, length);`  If length is 1024 then any offset > 0 would cause a problem.

Comment: I see, i thought the last 2 arguments were start and end index, but they are start index and length!